# DS90UB948-Q1 internal pattern generator

Tags: i2c, video, lvds, deserialiser

Does anyone have prior experience with [DS90UB948-Q1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90ub948-q1.pdf) FPD-Link III Deserializer deserialiser from Texas Instruments ? I am trying to configure the internal pattern generator block sending I2C commands. [This application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla132d/snla132d.pdf) describes what registers to be configured. The registers are configured using an indirect addressing method. PGIA is the indirect register for addresses and PGID is the indirect register for data. PGIA has to be configured first, before data is placed in PGID. The problem is that when I write in PGID data register the deserialiser stops sending the ACK bit (found out using a logic analyser) and doesn't respond to commands anymore, a hardware reset needs to be performed.